# How to get the shortest match between two words?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to wrap my head around regular expressions, and still can't figure one thing out.

Let's say we have this string:

```
const text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?'
```

If I use `text.match(/(dog)([^]+)(lazy)/)`, it gives me `dog. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy"`.

Instead I'm trying to get something like this: `"dog reacted, was it really lazy"`.

How do I format the regular expression, to get the shortest match between the first and the second word?

Comment: You should prevent matching dog again until you match lazy `\bdog\b(?:(?!\bdog\b).)*\blazy\b` https://regex101.com/r/5Ve9Jz/1 See this page about [Tempered Greedy Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat)

Comment: Try `\bdog\b(?:(?!\bdog\b)[^.])*?\blazy\b`

Comment: Thank you very much for help.  Non-capturing group is what I was missing. However I need to use capturing group instead of boundary, because I can't guarantee that the search term will be separated by spaces. So this worked for me `(dog)(?:(?!(dog))[^])+?(lazy)`.